# jwt token not working in digitalocean droplet after snapshot

Tags: php, jwt

We have developed a wep app with codeigniter 4 with API using JWT access token.

This app works well in our VPS out of digital ocean but in our droplet, it always returns “error”: `Missing or invalid jwt access token.`

We validated the JWT token on the test website at `https://jwt.io` and the token is generating perfectly with our signature, We created this droplet from snapshot.

The methods that don´t need token like `signin` and `status` works well.

Maybe it is a droplet configuration issue. Some idea how to solve this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Without code, there isn’t much that we can tell you.

Comment: I wonder if it might be related to timezone or time settings?